# NSOperationQueue's addOperation: operation is finished and cannot be enqueued?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperationqueue, cloudkit, nsblockoperation

**Note:**
This is merely a proof-of-concept.
The real background task will be to continuously request 'HTTP Get' of raw data and to display it via main thread; on demand.

**Scenario:**
1) Toggle a background task (loop) on demand. 
2) Background task notifies main thread UI per iteration.
3) Only one (1) block operation runs in the queue.

**Modus Operandus**
1) Use NSBlockOperation to contain the background code.
2) Use a regional BOOL to toggle the loop; via IBAction.

**Problems**
1) The compiler is flagging the BOOL 'isRunning' as a *strong* link:

> Capturing 'self' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain
>   cycle.

2) I checked to see if any operations are on the queue before attempting to add the block operation.  
But I always get the following error:

> -[NSOperationQueue addOperation:]: operation is finished and cannot be enqueued

This proof-of-concept appears to be working, besides the stated problems.

Question:
1) Why is the compile flagging the BOOL 'running' as a strong line when it's merely a scaler? 
2) Why can't I reuse the NSOperationQueue via adding another NSBlockOperation if none is found in the queue?

The following is the entire code:

```
#define START 0
#define STOP 1

@interface ricViewController ()
@property (assign) BOOL running;
@end

@implementation ricViewController {
    NSOperationQueue *operationQueue;
    NSBlockOperation *blockOperation;
    void (^backgroundBlock)(void);
}

@synthesize running = isRunning;

#pragma mark - ViewController methods

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
    [operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
    [operationQueue setName:@"RicQueue"];
    [self buildBackgroundBlock];
    blockOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:backgroundBlock];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    operationQueue = nil;
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma mark - Local methods

- (void)buildBackgroundBlock {
    static int k = 0;
    backgroundBlock = ^{
        while (isRunning) {   // 1) *** compiler warning flag: strong link warning ***
            sleep(1);
            if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
                NSLog(@"{backgroundBlock} *** Main Thread *** ***");
            } else {
                 NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{backgroundBlock} count = %i", k++];
                 NSLog(myString);
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    self.dataLabel.text = myString;
                });

            }
        }
    };
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma - Action methods

- (IBAction)exitAction:(UIButton *)sender {
    exit(0);
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

- (IBAction)segmentedAction:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {

    switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case START:
            NSLog(@"START");
            self.running = YES;
            if (operationQueue.operationCount < 1) {
                [operationQueue addOperation:blockOperation]; // 2) *** fatal error on 2nd pass.
            }
            break;
        case STOP:
            NSLog(@"STOP");
            self.running = NO;
            break;
    }
    return;
}

@end
```

The console output:

```
BackgroundTask[3759:c07] STOP
BackgroundTask[3759:c07] START
BackgroundTask[3759:1303] {backgroundBlock} count = 0
BackgroundTask[3759:1303] {backgroundBlock} count = 1
BackgroundTask[3759:1303] {backgroundBlock} count = 2
BackgroundTask[3759:1303] {backgroundBlock} count = 3
BackgroundTask[3759:1303] {backgroundBlock} count = 4
BackgroundTask[3759:1303] {backgroundBlock} count = 5
BackgroundTask[3759:1303] {backgroundBlock} count = 6
BackgroundTask[3759:1303] {backgroundBlock} count = 7
BackgroundTask[3759:c07] STOP
BackgroundTask[3759:1303] {backgroundBlock} count = 8
```

Answer (score 5):

I did further research and found that 
*** I must *re-create* the NSBlockOperation object per each 'addOperation' ***, since NSOperationQueue *refuses* to re-queue the SAME NSOperation object.

Hence the following solution:

```
- (IBAction)segmentedAction:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
    switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case START:
            NSLog(@"START");
            self.running = YES;
            blockOperation = nil;
            [self buildBackgroundBlock];
            blockOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:backgroundBlock];
            [operationQueue addOperation:blockOperation];
            break;
        case STOP:
            NSLog(@"STOP");
            self.running = NO;
            break;
    }
}
```

...as for the compiler associates the BOOL 'isRunning' with the static 'self':

> Capturing 'self' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retrain
>   cycle.

All  references to 'self' should be via a weak link.

```
- (void)buildBackgroundBlock {
    static int k = 0;
    BOOL myRunning = isRunning;
    __weak ricViewController *weakObject = self;

    backgroundBlock = ^{
        while (myRunning) {
            sleep(1);
            if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
                NSLog(@"{backgroundBlock} *** Main Thread *** ***");
            } else {
                NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{backgroundBlock} count = %i", k++];
                NSLog(myString);
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                weakObject.dataLabel.text = [myString copy];
                });
            }
        }
    };
}
```